# Uploaded media files 404 on production but show up hours later

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

We've built a custom front end for users to post threads and upload images on top of Sitecore 9. Recently, we moved the user generated content to it's own database, so the media files are no longer in the proper sitecore 'media gallery'. Also, file storage is on a networked share. Uploading images works just fine. It's immediately after where the problem lies.

Upon image upload, our rest api returns the media url from the MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(itemId). This also works. It returns a valid url, it is formatted correctly and should resolve. Unfortunately, for some time after, the url does the sitecore dance an 302s to our 404 page.

I can see the image through the content editor and our custom content handler injects the image folder node into both master and web databases.

Why would the link manager be able to find the url, but the image is not available? I uploaded something yesterday afternoon, an when I checked this morning, the image is now available on the site. Any information or suggestions are appreciated.

I have tried saving the image multiple times hoping that this might trigger whatever mystical Sitecore event that causes images to show. Since there isn't a publish due to the separate database, I can't try that. I've removed all versions thinking it couldn't default to a particular language. Nothing. Only time seems to make the images visible. The code below works just fine. I'm just putting it here to to show some work.

```cs
public MediaItem UploadSimpleMedia(MediaGallerySimpleUploadRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var destinationFolder = request.ParentItemId != null
            ? _content.GetItem<Item>(request.ParentItemId.Value)
            : _content.GetItem<Item>(_publicLibraryPath + "/embeded");

        var name = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Name)
            ? ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(request.Name)
            : ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(request.Files[0].FileName);

        var creator = new MediaCreator();
        var tags = request.Tags != null ? request.Tags.Split(',') : new string[0];
        var tagIds = _tagService.GetTagIds(tags);
        var tagIdString = string.Join(",", tagIds);

        var options = new MediaCreatorOptions()
        {
            AlternateText = request.Name,
            FileBased = true,
            IncludeExtensionInItemName = false,
            Versioned = false,
            Destination = $"{destinationFolder.Paths.Path}/{name}",
            Database = Factory.GetDatabase("content")
        };

        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        using (new DatabaseCacheDisabler())
        {
            MediaItem item = creator.CreateFromStream(request.Files[0].InputStream, request.Files[0].FileName, options);

            item.BeginEdit();
            item.InnerItem["Title"] = request.Name;
            item.InnerItem["Description"] = request.Description;
            item.InnerItem["__Semantics"] = tagIdString;

            // Sitecore won't calculate MIME Type or File Size automatically unless you upload directly
            // to the Sitecore Media Library. We're uploading in-place for private groups for permission inheritance
            // and now because of indexing, they are getting uploaded to /Community/Gallery/Files if not private.

            item.InnerItem["Size"] = request.Files[0].ContentLength.ToString();
            item.InnerItem["Mime Type"] = request.Files[0].ContentType;

            item.EndEdit();

            // Just pausing here to reflect on why Sitecore is so sexily complicated
            // that it takes time to display an image on the CD, but has no problem giving
            // up the media url
            CacheManager.GetHtmlCache(Sitecore.Context.Site);
            _searchService.RefreshIndex(item.ID.Guid);
            var fromDatabase = _content.GetItem<Item>(item.ID.Guid);

            return fromDatabase;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(this.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName, ex);
        _logger.Trace(ex.StackTrace);
    }

    return null;
}
```

I don't get any error messages either in our custom logs or the default sitecore logs. Images just aren't resolving. Is it caching? I've even nuked all caches by calling CacheManager.ClearAllCaches().

Comment: There is a setting called _"Media.AlwaysAppendRevision"_ in Sitecore.config, if it is set to _"true"_ then Sitecore will generate a unique URL for every item revision by adding a "rev" query string parameter when you call `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item)`. This means that every time an item is revised, a new URL is generated. Try to enable this setting to check whether it is a cache related issue or not.

Comment: I think what is happening is we've reached the upper limit of items in a folder. We are storing our files in unstructured folders instead of buckets. Don't quote me on this, but I think there is some magic happening behind the scenes with the link database. Theory: When an item gets created, the link manager goes up to the parent item and rebuilds from there. With >1000+ items, this seems to take a long time. We are going to try to switch to buckets and see if the problem resolves. Will report back.